# How do I redirect a post url to a custom url?

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, htaccess

I've created a page that loops posts. Each post acts as a category link so that when you click it brings you to a category archive.

My issue is that wordpress somehow overrides my htaccess and redirects me to the single.php post.

So ill have a category page called 'Neighborhoods'. Within 'Neighborhoods' I have a post called 'Highland Park'.  When I click 'Highland Park' it brings you to the the single.php not the archive.php of 'Highland Park.'

Note:  I uploaded my wordpress files into a folder called 'pages'.  In my htaccess file I have a rewrite where 'neighborhoods/' is 'pages/category/neighborhoods/'

Is there a solution? Am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Well, actually Wordpress provides `wp redirect` function. And here is a small plugin I've used a while back

```
<?php
$redirect_meta_key = 'redirect_to';

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_this');

function redirect_this($nothing)
{
    global $wp_query, $redirect_meta_key;

    if(is_single() || is_page()) {
        $redirect = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, $redirect_meta_key, true);
        if('' != $redirect) {
            wp_redirect($redirect);
            header("Status: 302");
            exit;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

No all you have to do is to it in a custom field `redirect_to` with a value of absolute path to the other page, or alternatively, add a custom meta box

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a generic redirect solution in my templates that uses custom fields. In my **functions.php** I have this function:

```php
if (!function_exists('sumo_redirect')):
/**
 * Put this at the very top of a page and give it the current page id. It then
 * checks if there is a redirect_to custom field with another page id that it
 * can redirect to.
 *
 * @param    int    $post_id    The current page.
 */
function sumo_redirect($post_id)
{
    $redirect_to_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'redirect', TRUE);
    if (strlen($redirect_to_meta) > 0)
    {
        $redirect_to = (int) $redirect_to_meta;

        header( "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" );
        header( "Location: " . get_permalink($redirect_to) );
        die();
    }
}
endif;
```

And in my page template (or in your case the post template; single.php) I have this at the very top of the file:

```
<?php sumo_redirect($post->ID) ?>
```

Now you can edit your post and add to it a custom field named *redirect*, enter a post id and it will redirect to that. You might want to alter the function to also accept strings as the redirect destination (or even something more advanced like `category:12`, `post:34`, `url:http://google.com` etc).

Comment: put `die()` or `exit()` after header, because in some cases the current script will continue to run...